# Best way to implement a google+ like slide out menu?

Tags: android, menu, implementation

I am a newbie android developer who is  trying to build an application which uses a fly in menu(similar to  google+, fb, steam, youtube). I found https://github.com/jfeinstein10/SlidingMenu  works well for my needs. Now my question is , what is the most efficent way to to use this library

This is one of my activities

```
public class ExampleActivity2 extends SlidingActivity implements OnItemClickListener{

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        setBehindContentView(R.layout.list);
        getSlidingMenu().setBehindOffsetRes(R.dimen.actionbar_home_width);
        Button btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);

        //ListClass l=new ListClass(getApplicationContext());

        ListView lv=(ListView) findViewById(R.id.lvname);
        String[] values = new String[] { "Android", "iPhone", "WindowsMobile",
                  "Blackberry", "WebOS", "Ubuntu", "Windows7", "Max OS X",
                  "Linux", "OS/2" };
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                  android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, android.R.id.text1, values);

                // Assign adapter to ListView
                lv.setAdapter(adapter); 
                lv.setOnItemClickListener(this);
                getActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
    }

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) {
        switch(arg2){
        case 1:
            Intent myIntent = new Intent(this,TestClass.class);
            startActivity(myIntent);
            break;

        }

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case android.R.id.home:
                // app icon in action bar clicked; go home
               toggle();
                return true;
            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }

}
```

As u you can see, this implementation requires me to populate the side menu for every activity that I use it. 
(In this example , when the user chooses item 1 from the side menu, I start a new activity called TestClass where I have to populate the listview  and implement the onitemlistener again).

I want a way to move the whole listView code(with the onitemclicklistener) to a seperate file that can be called for all activities(the detail views).I tried to move the code to a different class but eclipse throws a  null point exception error. I would highly appreciate it if someone can guide me with an example on how to use this library(I didnt find the samples very useful). Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 2):

If you want to avoid the hustle of coding yourself, I would recommend using [scringo](http://www.scringo.com).  It's kind of a plugin that you can add to your app and has the slidemenu like google+/FB/Youtube (you can choose if the menu is on the right or left). 
It also has built in features that you can choose to use (like chat, invite friends, etc...), and of course add your own commands to the menu.

Answer (score 0):

There is one simple way you can consolidate the entire thing, is by using a `BaseActivity` class which has all the common stuff like your slide menu setup related code. Now all activities which require the sliding menu feature can extend `BaseActivity` instead of `SlidingActivity`

Something like this:

```
public class BaseActivity extends SlidingActivity implements OnItemClickListener{

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        //content view is set by the activity which extends BaseActivity
        setBehindContentView(R.layout.list);
        getSlidingMenu().setBehindOffsetRes(R.dimen.actionbar_home_width);
        //Button btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);

        //ListClass l=new ListClass(getApplicationContext());

        ListView lv=(ListView) findViewById(R.id.lvname);
        String[] values = new String[] { "Android", "iPhone", "WindowsMobile",
                  "Blackberry", "WebOS", "Ubuntu", "Windows7", "Max OS X",
                  "Linux", "OS/2" };
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                  android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, android.R.id.text1, values);

                // Assign adapter to ListView
        lv.setAdapter(adapter); 
        lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            /*
             * (non-Javadoc)
             * 
             * @see
             * android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener#onItemClick
             * (android.widget.AdapterView, android.view.View, int, long)
             */
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                    int position, long id) {
                switch(arg2){
                    case 1:
                        Intent myIntent = new Intent(this,TestClass.class);
                        startActivity(myIntent);
                        break;
                }
            }
        });
        getActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case android.R.id.home:
                // app icon in action bar clicked; go home
               toggle();
                return true;
            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }

}
```

And your example activity looks something like this:

```
public class ExampleActivity2 extends BaseActivity{

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        Button btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
    }
}
```

**Always remember to call super or else you will get runtime exceptions**